# Accessing a property/method of an object inside a collection of hashes

Tags: ruby

For whatever reason, I cannot access the position property inside the each loop.

This always give me a no method error. I've tried making the @position variable accessable a million different ways, and nothing seems to work.

```
class Recipe
    attr_accessor :directions
    def initialize(name,directions)
        @directions = directions
    end

    def directions
        @directions
    end

    def make
        ingredients = []
        @directions.each do |dir|
            puts dir[:ingredient].position
            #puts ingredient.position
            #direction[:ingredient].position = direction[:position]
            #ingredients.push(direction[:ingredient])
        end
    end
end

class Ingredient

    attr_accessor :name, :position
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @position = nil
        @state = nil
    end

end


bread = Ingredient.new("bread")
cheese = Ingredient.new("cheese")

sandwich_recipe = Recipe.new("Sandwich",[
    { position: :on, ingredient: bread },
    { position: :on, ingredidnt: cheese }
])

sandwich = sandwich_recipe.make
#sandwich.inspect
```

error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `position' for nil:NilClass
```

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your call to the `Recipe` constructor:

```
sandwich_recipe = Recipe.new("Sandwich",[
    { position: :on, ingredient: bread },
    { position: :on, ingredidnt: cheese }
])                          ^
```

You mispelled `ingredient`.

That being said, you never set the `@position` instance variable to anything but `nil`, so it will never have a value.

I think what you really want to do is pass the position to the `Ingredient` constructor, then pass the array of ingredients to the `Recipe` constructor.

```
class Ingredient
    attr_accessor :name, :position

    def initialize(name, position)
        @name = name
        @position = position
    end
end

bread  = Ingredient.new("bread",  "on")
cheese = Ingredient.new("cheese", "on")

sandwich_recipe = Recipe.new("Sandwich", [bread, cheese])
sandwich = sandwich_recipe.make
```

Comment: Arg, foiled by a spelling mistake. I feel pretty stupid now. I really have to start doing those kinds of checks when I spend over an hour on something...

Anyway, thanks a ton for this!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. However I think your code should like this for it to work.

```
class Recipe
    attr_accessor :directions
    def initialize(name,directions)
        @directions = directions
    end

    def directions
        @directions
    end

    def make
        ingredients = []
        @directions.each do |element|
            puts element.name
            puts element.position
            #puts ingredient.position
            #direction[:ingredient].position = direction[:position]
            #ingredients.push(direction[:ingredient])
        end
    end
end

class Ingredient

    attr_accessor :name, :position
    def initialize(name, position)
        @name = name
        @position = position
        @state = nil
    end

end


bread = Ingredient.new("bread", "on")
cheese = Ingredient.new("cheese", "on")

sandwich_recipe = Recipe.new("Sandwich",[ bread, cheese ])
sandwich = sandwich_recipe.make
```